# using mutlipart format with api gateway proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, proxy, aws-api-gateway

I'm moving an existing API to use aws lambdas, but need to keep the current version running so I'm setting up aws gateway to proxy the existing api.

We have one api route which is a file upload. The headers we set are `api-key` and `api-name` which are being passed properly by api gateway, but I'm getting an error that says `missing boundary header`.

However, the boundary header is part of the content-type `Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x` so I don't think I can set that directly. I was hoping it would get passed through.

Any suggestions on routing a file upload proxy through aws api gateway?

Comment: I think you'll find that [API Gateway is not really suited handling to binary data](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220351&tstart=0) in its current version.

Comment: I don't see an easy way to build a file upload proxy via API Gateway because like Michael said API Gateway doesn't handle binary data very well currently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. On the "Method Request", pass through the *Content-Type* HTTP Request Header
2. Tick *Required*
3. On the "Integration Request", create a "Mapping Template" for Content Type: *multipart/form-data*
4. Set "Request body passthrough" to *When there are no templates defined*